# Access Android Phone on local wireless network from Windows device

Tags: windows, wi-fi

Is what the subject implies possible?
Typing `\\{phone IP}` doesn't seem to work as it would with other Windows running devices on the same network.

Thank you.

Comment: If you mean you want to remote-control the Android phone, that's been addressed in this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1931/1683

Comment: This is also quite similar (but not exactly the same) to this question: [Is there a SMB Server app that does not require root access?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/is-there-a-smb-server-app-that-does-not-require-root-access)

Comment: No, no, no, I don't mean remote control but rather file sharing. I want to type `\\192.168.0.100` and see files in my phone as I would if it was plugged into the USB of my PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work seamlessly you would need an SMB server on your phone.  There is such an app, available via [this forum thread](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/samba-server-for-android/).  It needs root, and it looks like results vary by device.  At least one reason why root is required is that normal users aren't allowed to open ports below 1024, whilst by convention, SMB servers use ports 135-139.

An alternative is the [On Air (Wifi Disk)](http://www.appbrain.com/app/on-air-%28wifi-disk%29/com.bw.onair) app, available in the market.  Whilst not quite seamless, this does give you access to your SD card via AppleTalk, WebDAV or good old FTP.  I've just tested with an HTC Desire HD and Windows XP over WebDAV and it appears to work well.

The Windows XP WebDAV client is a bit ropey, but that's not really the fault of Android or On Air :)

The On Air app itself warns of issues using the built-in WebDAV clients for Vista and Windows 7, and recommends a standalone client.

Comment: I wonder why it has to be so complicated considering the FAT is FAT32 and Windows is perfectly capable of reading that.

Comment: Wandering off of this particular Stack Exchange's subject a little, but I think you need to understand that when you enter \\192.168.0.100 on your PC, you're not *actually* looking directly at the target machine's disk, but rather connecting to a server on that machine. Windows just happens to make that server quite easy to configure, by simply 'sharing a folder'. A phone has different requirements from a desktop PC (battery usage, for instance) so it's understandable that you get less of this kind of functionality 'in the box'.

Answer (score -1):

well in that case u can use software data cable in your android phone. it'll install the ftp server on your phone and you can get access to your phone storage from the browser.. remember they should be in the same network....

Comment: miki, I guess the downvote is because you've missed the link to that app (and people thinking about "stupid WiFi cables?!?! WTF?!?" :) Maybe you want to [edit] your answer and add the link?