# Access to Android phone's SD card from PC, without USB

Tags: internal-storage, bluetooth, usb-connection-mode, usb-mass-storage

This question is classical: *how to access the phone's SD card from PC?*
 Of course USB works very well, but I'm looking for a wireless solution.

I've already tried various apps and solutions, but very often, with these wireless solutions, **I didn't have real full access** to the SD card, like I would have for a USB flashdrive or a harddrive or a CD-ROM. (see image below)

Thus my question is : **how to access the phone's SD card from PC, wirelessly, with full access to SD card from PC?**  (I mean: having a drive letter F: and being able to run .bat batch files on this SD card from the PC; this works when connecting with USB cable)

*Note: I've tried tools like installing "FTP server" on phone, connecting by wifi, and then using tools on PC that make FTP look like a removable disk. But this was very tricky, and at the end didn't work well. And above all it was not handy on every day use.*

[image]

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: @MatthewRead I'm going to do it soon. Can this help?

Comment: What you're looking for is to setup your phone as a **SMB server**. [This question and answers](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/using-smb-server-without-root-access) has a lot of good information about why you can't really do it unless your phone is rooted. It also has a couple alternative workarounds.

Comment: @Basj I'm aware of some FTP/WebDAV server apps which would start the server automatically as soon as you launch them. You can use such an app with an automation app, like Tasker/MacroDroid/Automate in such a way that whenever hotspot is turned on or device is connected to a particular Wi-Fi, launch the server app. In your PC, all you would have to do is refresh Explorer. Have you already tried this approach?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use FTP to achieve this...

You can try it too. All you'll just need is an understanding of how ftp works which is very basic by the way.

Download any app that provides an ftp server on your android devices, they are always pretty easy to use. I currently use use ES File explorer's functionality to do this.

As shown here

[image: ES File] [image: Remote Manager]

Selecting Remote Manager is all you need.

After the ftp services has started on your android device and is on the same network as your computer, you should then spring up windows explorer [win-key + E] or even a web browser and enter ftp://phones_ip_address:ftp_listening_port into the address bar

**Note:** the column separating address and port.
Lemme know if you get this

Comment: I just read all of your post and found out you already tried stuffs like this... forgive my being forward

Comment: Indeed, I already tried things like that, but at the end there's no real time gain in comparison to plugging a USB cable if I need to : open FTP app, start the server, wait for the connection time in Windows Explorer (it's really long to explore a FTP drive in windows explorer). 
I was looking for a more direct solution

Comment: Rather than using the FTP support built into Windows File Explorer (which is not really much good), I would recommend using a dedicated FTP client such as FileZilla.  Doing so will make your life _much_ easier.

Comment: @PaulSanders Filezilla is unable to find the sd card. Only the internal storage

Comment: @Gulzar sd card?  On Windows?

Comment: @PaulSanders, Yes, the OP was about reading the sd card, wirelessly. I am on Windows and filezilla works great, but not for the sd card